# Get folder name in specified directory?

Tags: vb.net

There is a one folder located in a directory, lets say its in

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

it's different on everyuser, for example **1rituum9.default** named folder.

Tried this without any luck, it messages empty.

```
Dim filepath As String = "%Appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(filepath)
MessageBox.Show(fi.Name)
```

What is the correct way to get the folder name in specified directory ?

Comment: If you're looking at folders do you want IO.DirectoryInfo instead of FileInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim filepath As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") & "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(filepath)
MessageBox.Show(di.GetDirectories()(0).Name)
```

if there are more than one dirs u might need something like:

```
For Each Dir As IO.DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories()
ListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
Next
```

Edit: Fixed Code Line 1 - see comments

Comment: Strangely, I don't get any message. Is there something wrong ?

Comment: it seems that it won't resolve "%Appdata%". Try this: `Dim filepath As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") & "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"`

Comment: How can I use that name as dim ?

Comment: Lets say I should check if the folder name (we found with your method) exists. When I use --->  If (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") & "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\")) <-- What should I write there to check if the folder name we found exists ?

Comment: you can safe it like this: `Dim folder as String = filepath & di.GetDirectories()(0).Name` and then you check with 
`If system.io.directory.exists(folder) Then...`